# Get camera image Inside Iistview

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I have custom `Listview`. Inside it has one `Button` and `ImageView`.

on Button click Camera will open.(Camera Intent fired).

I want that captured Image (you also call as Bitmap) onto `ImageView` which is also a ListItem.

that means when i capture image and press Done button of camera then my imageview have to set that image.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private static int FILE_SELECT_CODE_1 = 0;
    function intentCamera(){
         Intent i = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         startActivityForResult(i, FILE_SELECT_CODE_1);


  }

private String getLastImagePath() {
        final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
        Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
                null, null, imageOrderBy);
        if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            // Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::id " + id);
            // Log.d(TAG, "getLastImageId::path " + fullPath);
            imageCursor.close();
            return fullPath;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE_1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         String lastImagePath = getLastImagePath();
         File fileImage = new File(lastImagePath);
         Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileImage);
         //now you can set the image example:
         ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
         img.setImageURI(u);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps,

1. start activity for result of camera intent from your activity.
2. after capturing picture control callback to `onActivityResult` of you activity.
3. handle path of image.
4. set that path to your image by setting property in your listview item position.